# ¿Filtrado por fecha en datatable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, datatable

estoy tratando de hacer un filtrado de dos datatable en un mismo archivo php, cuando inserto el codigo del filtro en una tabla me funciona a la perfección, pero cuando realizao el segundo filtrado de la segunda tabla y copio el mismo codigo, pero le cambio las variables para que sean diferentes, me deja de funcionar el filtrado de la primera tabla y no se por que?

aqui les dejo el codigo:
1°ra tabla

```
   <h6 class="text-justify" size="4">Busqueda por fecha</h6>
                      <table class="mb-2" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Fecha inicio:</td>
                            <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" id="min_1" name="min_1"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Fecha final:</td>
                            <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" id="max_1" name="max_1"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>

                         <table id="reporte-ventas" name="reporte-ventas" class="table  table-striped">
                                    <thead class="text-center">
                                        <tr class="thead-dark">
                                            <th class="border-top-0">#</th>
                                            <th class="border-top-0 evita_1" hidden>Fecha</th>
                                            <th class="border-top-0">Fecha</th>
                                            <th class="border-top-0">No. Orden</th>
                                            <th class="border-top-0">Usuario</th>
```

2°da tabla

```
    <h6 class="text-justify" size="4">Busqueda por fecha</h6>
                      <table class="mb-2" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Fecha inicio:</td>
                            <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" id="min_date" name="min_date"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Fecha final:</td>
                            <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" id="max_date" name="max_date"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                  <table id="reporte-ventas-digitales" name="reporte-ventas-digitales" class="table  table-striped">
                                <thead class="text-center">
                                    <tr class="thead-dark">
                                        <th class="border-top-0">#</th>
                                        <th class="border-top-0 evita_2" hidden>Fecha</th>
                                        <th class="border-top-0">Fecha</th>
                                        <th class="border-top-0">No. Orden</th>
                                        <th class="border-top-0">Usuario</th>
```

script de javascript

```
**<script type="text/javascript">
var minDate_1, endDate_1;
var startDate, endDate;


$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min_1 = minDate_1.val();
    var max_1 = endDate_1.val();
    var date_1 = new Date( data[1] ).setHours(0,0,0,0);

    if (min_1 == null && max_1 == null) { return true; }
    if (min_1 == null && date_1 <= max_1) { return true; }
    if (max_1 == null && date_1 >= min_1) { return true; }
    if (date_1 <= max_1 && date_1 >= min_1) { return true; }
    return false;
  }
);

    $(document).ready(function() {
      minDate_1 = new DateTime($('#min_1'), {
        format: 'L',
      });
      endDate_1 = new DateTime($('#max_1'), {
        format: 'L',
      });
        /* TABLA REPORTE VENTAS*/
      var table_1 = $('#reporte-ventas').DataTable({
            language: {
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                    "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst": "Primero",
                        "sLast":"Último",
                        "sNext":"Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                     },
                     "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
                },
            //para usar los botones
            responsive: "true",
            dom: 'Bfrtilp',
            buttons: [{
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
                    titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                    className: 'btn btn-success',
                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':not(.evita_1)',
                                    },
                    filename: 'Reporte_ventas_ <?php echo date('Y:m:d:m:s') ?>'
                },
                {`introducir el código aquí`
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
                    titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                    className: 'btn btn-danger',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':not(.evita_1)',
                                    },
                    filename: 'Reporte_ventas_ <?php echo date('Y:m:d:m:s') ?>'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
                    titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                    className: 'btn btn-info',
                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':not(.evita_1)',
                                    },
                    filename: 'Reporte_ventas_ <?php echo date('Y:m:d:m:s') ?>'
                },
            ]
        });

        $('#min_1, #max_1').on('change', function () {
          table_1.draw();
        });
        /* TABLA REPORTE VENTAS */
        /* TABLA REPORTE VENTAS DIGITALES */
        startDate = new DateTime($('#min_date'), {
          format: 'L',
        });
        endDate = new DateTime($('#max_date'), {
          format: 'L',
        });

        var table_2 = $('#reporte-ventas-digitales').DataTable({
            language: {
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                    "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst": "Primero",
                        "sLast":"Último",
                        "sNext":"Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                     },
                     "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
                },
            //para usar los botones
            responsive: "true",
            dom: 'Bfrtilp',
            buttons: [{
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
                    titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                    className: 'btn btn-success',
                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':not(.evita_2)',
                                    },
                    filename: 'Reporte_ventas_digitales_ <?php echo date('Y:m:d:m:s') ?>'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
                    titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                    className: 'btn btn-danger',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':not(.evita_2)',
                                    },
                    filename: 'Reporte_ventas_digitales_ <?php echo date('Y:m:d:m:s') ?>'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
                    titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                    className: 'btn btn-info',
                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':not(.evita_2)',
                                    },
                    filename: 'Reporte_ventas_digitales_ <?php echo date('Y:m:d:m:s') ?>'
                },
            ]
        });
        $('#min_date, #max_date').on('change', function () {
          table_2.draw();
        });
        /* TABLA REPORTE VENTAS DIGITALEs */
    });
</script>**
```

Busque información acerca si me podría solucionar el problema y me guie con esta pagina https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717543/how-do-i-filter-date-range-in-datatables contiene otras formas de hacer el proceso de filtrado pero no me funciono como tal :(.

lo que espero es el siguiente resultado.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZfKt.png)

coloque la fecha y me arroje en las dos tablas el resultado que quiero.

les agradecería que me apoyaran en que parte me equivoque o una guia de como resolver este detalle que tengo.

Comment: No veo ninguna `table` con `id="reporte-ventas"`

Comment: Una disculpa ya corregí ese detalle, pondría todo mi código pero es demasiado

Comment: las dos tablas están en el mismo archivo, pero cada vez que coloco esta funcion: $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push( etc etc ya no me funciona nada, es decir una por cada tabla, la que me funciona ya no funciona si copio esa misma funcion con diferentes variables